# Scala Play (2.8) Project: after cloning from git, sbt run yields: java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

This question is a bit embarrassing to ask, but several searches have yielded no clear answer. I have created a Scala Play project (Play 2.8.1; sbt 1.3.4; Scala 2.13.1) using the command `sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8`  All works as expected. I added a few classes and objects of Scala code and experienced no problems in building and running on the Ubuntu 18.04 cmd line using sbt commands (e.g. `sbt run`, `sbt clean`).

Then I checked my code into a git repo and pushed to a remote repository. The project is a simple one, consisting only of a about 5 .scala files and some standard Play Framework front-end views. I made sure to push `build.sbt`, and the build.properties and plugins.sbt files under the `project` directory, in addition to my .scala files. I also checked in the `sbt` and `sbt.bat` scripts.

I cloned this git project into a new location.

I run the code, as always using `sbt run`. Some dependencies are pulled down. But before long I get an error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.`

I tried several times, and then again after running `sbt clean` just for good measure. I note that a brief grep revealed no clear `main()` candidates, but this was true also of my working code in the original--not the freshly cloned--local git repository. What do I need to do in order to insure that I or someone else can simply check out this or any other Play project from github, and run it successfully without this error? This ought to be automatic.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: May wish to delete this question. I leave the decision to other readers.

Answer (score 0):

Ooh, yuk. Despite checkng, it seems I pulled down an empty build.sbt file. I made sure the correct, non-empty `build.sbt` file was checked in, I pulled to get it, and the project built with no problem. Sorry for this.